# Can I omit the else in an inline javascript if statement?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use this and it doesn't appear to be working. I'm guessing it's just not an option, but want to confirm. Is this valid?

```
(if_it_is) ? thats_cool();
```

Comment: No, it's not optional. Use a binary operator instead (&&) as long as `thats_cool()` returns a value that evaluates to `true`.

Comment: Nope. It needs to have the `:` and some value following it. If you want, you could just create a function named `do_nothing()` that...well, does nothing.

Comment: user1048967, That is called `if() {}`.

Comment: @Jonathan It doesn't have to return boolean, as it'll be called if `if_it_is` evaluates to a truthy statement.

Comment: Dykam - I guess I will have to resort to typing the extra keystroke. wishful thinking I guess!

Comment: Just for the record, aside from the answer Sarfraz wrote below, you don't have to create a null function, it can simply be:

    (if_it_is) ? thats_cool() : 0;

That's a zero, not a winky face with the mouth open.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can use `&&` there:

```
if_it_is && thats_cool();
```

It is basically equal to:

```
if (your_expression){
   thats_cool();
}
```

Comment: Nice. You can do null coalescence with or's. var variable2 = variable1  || 'coalesceVal';

Comment: this is clever but it doesn't seem very intuitive to me. It doesn't read well. A question mark, I get. That, no.

Comment: @user1048967: People coming from other languages find it hard, but this is actually beauty and terseness of javascript you need to learn. At first at looks strange to everyone like I myself was confused but now using it effectively.

Comment: I'm still sad that there's no way to inline a conditional return statement other than `if(x) return y;` because you can't put a return statement in that nor the ternary expression.

Comment: using jshint it keeps saying that `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression. (W030)
source: 'jshint'`

Answer (score 9):

What you are trying to use is a [Ternary Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operator). You are missing the else part of it.

You could do something like:

```
(if_it_is) ? thats_cool() : function(){};
```

or

```
(if_it_is) ? thats_cool() : null;
```

Or, as others have suggested, you can avoid the ternary if you don't care about the else.

```
if_it_is && thats_cool();
```

In JavaScript, as well as most languages, these logical checks step from left to right. So it will first see if `if_it_is` is a ['trusy' value](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_boolean.asp) (`true`, `1`, a string other than `''`, et cetera). If that doesn't pass then it doesn't do the rest of the statement. If it does pass then it will execute `thats_cool` as the next check in the logic.

Think of it as the part inside of an if statement. Without the if. So it's kind of a shorthand of

```
if (if_it_is && thats_cool()) { }
```

Comment: Like your answer. It tells a story :)

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not valid.

The conditional operator takes the form `x ? y : z`. The third operand is not like the `else` in an `if`, it always has to be there.

Answer (score 3):

You can't accomplish that using the ternary operator, but you *can* use the short-circuit nature of `&&` to do what you want.

```
(if_it_is) && thats_cool();
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. `?:` is a ternary operator and MUST have all three of its operands.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. It's not an "inline if statement", it's the *ternary operator*, and that is, well… ternary.

```
(if_it_is) ? thats_cool() : null;
```

Since you do not seem to be interested in the return value of the operation, you could just write:

```
if (if_it_is) thats_cool();
```

though. That would also be better style than using a ternary.

Answer (score 0):

You miss the third component. Should be something like that:

```
(if_it_is) ? thats_cool() : not_too_cool();
```

The whole sense is:

```
condition ? do_something_if_condition_is_true : do_something_if_condition_is_false;
```