# ASP.NET: Client-side validation, server-side action

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, web-applications

For some reason I'm using HTML controls with `runat="server"`. One of these controls is a button. I have **client-side** validation function. I wan't to fire **server-side** action after successful **client-side** validation.

**HTML:**

```
<button type="button" id="webSubmit" 
runat="server" 
onclick="return $('#form1').valid();">Submit</button>
```

**Server side:**

```
protected void webSubmit_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //foo
}
```

When I click the button it validates the form but does not **postback** even if validation returns true.

It's generated by ASP.net:

```
<button onclick="return $('#form1').valid(); __doPostBack('webSubmit','')" 
id="webSubmit" type="button">Submit</button>
```

Comment: What do you have the `Button.UseSubmitBehavior Property ` set as is it True..? [Button.UseSubmit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed **onclick** code to this:

```
onclick="$('#form1').valid() && "
```

ASP.net generated code is:

```
<button onclick="$('#form1').valid() &&  __doPostBack('webSubmit','')" 
id="webSubmit" type="button">Submit</button>
```

It's equal to:

```
if ($('#form1').valid()){
__doPostBack('webSubmit','')
}
```

I got the idea from: [Can I omit the else in an inline javascript if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232907/can-i-omit-the-else-in-an-inline-javascript-if-statement)