# Ternary Operator (Inline If without Else)

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, inline, ternary-operator

I have two `checkbox` in a `<form>`. The `<form>` have an `onChange={this.checkBoxOnChange}` assigned to it which fires up `checkBoxOnChange(event){..}` function on every change in the form. I am trying to map *(Log)* the status *(ie whether they are checked or not)*. So, I've initially taken there value as `false` as they are not-checked then on each event I'm trying to change there value respectively *(ie if false the true & vice versa)*.

On following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232907/can-i-omit-the-else-in-an-inline-javascript-if-statement) SO post I tried this:

```
(event.target.value=='BILLDED') && billed=(!billed)
```

By doing this I get:

> Syntax error: Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression

Then I tried this:

```
(event.target.value=='BILLDED') ? (billed=(!billed)) : null
```

However, it gives me `BILLED:true` on every `onChange` (when clicked on BILLED `checkbox`)
This is code for checkbox inside render method:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <form onChange={this.checkBoxOnChange}>
        <input type="checkbox" name="invoicestatus" value="BILLDED" />BILLDED<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="invoicestatus" value="PENDING" />PENDING<br />
      </form>
      <ListData data={this.state.data}/>
    </div>
    );
  }
```

This is the `checkBoxOnChange()` function within that same class (Component):

```
   checkBoxOnChange(event){
    var billed=false;
    var pending=false;
  //  (event.target.value=='BILLDED') ? (billed=(!billed)) : null;
    (event.target.value=='BILLDED') && billed=(!billed)
  //  (event.target.value=='PENDING') ? pending=(!pending) : null;
    console.log("BILLDED:"+billed+"  PENDING:"+pending);
  }
```

- What's wrong with the code?
- Can I not use inline statement for this scenario?
- Is there any better, more concise approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What's wrong with the code?

You initialise the `billed` variable inside your event handler to `false`, that's why you always get `true` instead of toggling a state.

> Can I not use inline statement for this scenario?

You can, you just have to put the parenthesis in the right place:

```
(event.target.value == 'BILLDED') && (billed = !billed);
//                                   ^
```

> Is there any better, more concise approach?

Use a normal `if` statement. It's both shorter and more readable:

```
if (event.target.value == 'BILLDED') billed = !billed;
```

Comment: Got it. Can you please tell me waht would be the ideal place to initialize them then? Within `this.state()` inside `constructor` perhaps then? As there's no provision for global variable in React..

Comment: Yes, making it part of the state sounds like a good idea. It also depends on what you want to do with the value besides logging it, of course.

Answer (score 1):

> However, it gives me BILLED:true on every onChange (when clicked on
>   BILLED checkbox)

Is this not because you use a local variable as below

```
var billed=false;
```

which always starts as `false`?

Comment: Yes, but it shouldn't it change on every click event?

Comment: @NiladriSekharBasu From the code you posted no. Why would it? (it would change but the change would not persist right? since this is a local variable).

Comment: Ok. Got my mistake. But, then where it should be declared? In `this.state()` perhaps? As React does not have any provision for class variable..

Comment: @NiladriSekharBasu I think you should look into something which react calls "controlled components".