# Weird behavior of this.state

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

This is a follow up question of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46211641/ternary-operator-inline-if-without-else/46211725#comment79387124_46211725) question. I'm trying to `log` the value of two check boxes in terms of true or false.
   I have two `checkbox` in a `<form>`. The `<form>` have an `onChange={this.checkBoxOnChange}` assigned to it which fires up `checkBoxOnChange(event){..}` function on every change in the form. I am trying to map_(Log)_ the status *(ie whether they are checked or not)*. So, I've initially taken there value as `false` in `this.state()` inside `constructor()` as they are not-checked(initially) then on each event I'm trying to change there value respectively *(ie if false the true & vice versa)*.
But, when I'm trying to log their output they are printing in wrong order. Checking on checkbox is even changing value of another checkbox.

This is code for checkbox inside render method:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <form onChange={this.checkBoxOnChange.bind(this)}>
        <input type="checkbox" name="invoicestatus" value="BILLDED" />BILLDED<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="invoicestatus" value="PENDING" />PENDING<br />
      </form>
      <ListData data={this.state.data}/>
    </div>
    );
  }
};
```

This is the `checkBoxOnChange()` function within that same class (Component):

```
checkBoxOnChange(event){
   console.log("BILLDED"+this.state.billed+"PENDING"+this.state.pending);
   (event.target.value=='BILLDED') && (this.setState({billed:(!this.state.billed)}));
   (event.target.value=='PENDING') ? (this.setState({pending:(!this.state.pending)})) : null;
    console.log("BILLED"+this.state.billed+" PENDING"+this.state.pending);
  }
```

Initial value is being set as:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data:[],
      billed:false,
      pending:false
     }
  }
```

- Why I am getting wrong values?
- How do I make it work in proper order?

This question **is different** from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593202/why-calling-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately) SO post on following grounds:
 - Because both the solution to this question mention about [Uncontrolled Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) vs [Controlled Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)
 - Annnd there's also and awesome `setState()` feature of React [prevState](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate)  by which I was **(& would be)** unaware of, if I'd (or someone else) follows above mentioned post.

Comment: Is there any reason you are using uncontrolled input elements instead of controlled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues with your approach.

1. You are using uncontrolled input elements but are still using storing their value to `state`. Either use uncontrolled or uncontrolled components, not a mix. More info [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) and [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).
2. When updating the state with a value that depends on the previous state value, you should not use the function updater form rather than the object form. More info, [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

   > If you need to set the state based on the previous state, read about the updater argument.
3. You should be aware that `setState()` is asynchronous, so logging to the console immediately after updating the state is most likely going to give you the previous state. More info [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

   > `setState()` does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading `this.state` right after calling `setState()` a potential pitfall.

---

Here's how I would do it:

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      pending: false,
      billed: false
    };
  }

  togglePending = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({pending: !prevState.pending}));
  }

  toggleBilled = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({billed: !prevState.billed}));
  }

  render() {
    let {pending, billed} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="invoicestatus" checked={billed} onChange={this.toggleBilled} value="BILLDED" />BILLDED<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="invoicestatus" checked={pending} onChange={this.togglePending} value="PENDING" />PENDING<br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

---

If you insist on using your approach, here's how to fix it:

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      pending: false,
      billed: false
    };
  }

  checkBoxOnChange(event){
    console.log("BILLDED"+this.state.billed+"PENDING"+this.state.pending);
    let obj = {};
    if (event.target.value == 'BILLDED') {
      this.setState({billed: !this.state.billed}, () => {
        console.log("BILLED"+this.state.billed+" PENDING"+this.state.pending);
      });
    } else if(event.target.value=='PENDING') {
      this.setState({pending: !this.state.pending}, () => {
        console.log("BILLED"+this.state.billed+" PENDING"+this.state.pending);
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <form onChange={this.checkBoxOnChange.bind(this)}>
        <input type="checkbox" name="invoicestatus" value="BILLDED" />BILLDED<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="invoicestatus" value="PENDING" />PENDING<br />
      </form>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: In your approach where you would place the log in order to print both the values in correct order?

Comment: @NiladriSekharBasu, I would log them normally just *before* each `setState()` - just like you did. Then, I would also log inside the callback for each `setState()`. See my second hidden snippet how I do that.

Comment: Just a follow up question. Why passing a log printer function(which is defined elsewhere within the same class) does not yield correct value?

Comment: @NiladriSekharBasu, not sure what you mean. I'd have to take a closer look. Post a new question with code and then send me the link to it?

Comment: Will surely do :).

Comment: And in your answer in first point u mean _controlled or uncontrolled components_ instead of _uncontrolled or uncontrolled components_ ri8?

Comment: kindly see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46237553/why-only-one-component-is-re-rendering-immediately-and-other-is-not) question

Answer (score 3):

You are over complicating things in my opinion.
Instead of using [uncontrolled](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) component use use [controlled](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) components.
Just set a handler for each checkbox:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pending: false,
      billed: false
    };

    this.togglePending = this.togglePending.bind(this);
    this.toggleBilled = this.toggleBilled.bind(this);
  }

  togglePending() {
    this.setState({
      pending: !this.state.pending
    });
  }

  toggleBilled() {
    this.setState({
      billed: !this.state.billed
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { pending, billed } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="invoicestatus"
          checked={billed}
          onChange={this.toggleBilled}
          value="BILLDED"
        />BILLDED<br />
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="invoicestatus"
          checked={pending}
          onChange={this.togglePending}
          value="PENDING"
        />PENDING<br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```